# Does EJS support nested loops?

Tags: ejs

The outer loop will not iterate unless I remove the nested loop.  Anyone have any ideas?

```
    <% for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){ %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= users[i].firstname %></td>
            <td><%= users[i].lastname %></td>

            <td><select class="assign_dev"><option value="unassigned">unassigned</option>

              <% for (var i = 0; i < developers.length; i++) { %>  <!-- nested loop not working -->
                <option value="<%= developers[i]._id %>"><%= developers[i].firstname %>
              <% } %>

            </select></td>


        </tr>
    <% } %>
```

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: If I could find any references to it, I wouldn't be asking here.

Comment: use another variable name instead of `i` in the inner loop for iteration

Comment: You are totally right!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're reusing the variable `i`. Try to rename it to `j` in the inner loop.